# Is there any JSON tag filtering example?

Tags: python, json

I have one json file and i need to list all "selftext" elements of all data. 
Any example of it ?

data example

```
{   "data": [
    {      
        "selftext": "hello there",
        "textex": true,

   },
```

Comment: So the output is `["hello there"]` ?

Comment: `for d in json['data']: d.get('selftext')`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Output is ["selftext_1_text","selftext_2_text"..]

Comment: @ch3steR TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to find a key from an arbitrary json at an arbitrary level, you should use recursion:

```
def findkey(data, key, resul = None):
    if resul is None: resul=[]                # initialize an empty list for the results
    if isinstance(data, list):                # walk down into lists
        for d in data:
            findkey(d, key, resul)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):              # dict processing
        for k,v in data.items():
            if (k == key) and isinstance(v, str):    # the expected key and a string value?
                resul.append(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict):
                findkey(v, key, resul)        # recurse if value is a list or a dict
    return resul
```

Example:

```
>>> data = {   "data": [
    {
        "selftext": "hello there",
        "textex": True,

   },
  ]}
>>> findkey(data, 'selftext')
['hello there']
```